# Object is possibly 'null', Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to resolve this problem but I can't.
The value in my html says: **Object is possibly 'null'** and **Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.**

**HTML**

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedProvincia" (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)" name="provincias" id="ps-prov" class="form-select">
      <option *ngFor="let provincias of provincias" value="{{provincias.code}}">{{provincias.label}}</option>
      </select>
```

**TS**

```
 onSelect(code: string): void {
    this.municipios = this.newPersonService
      .getMunicipios()
      .filter((item) => item.parent_code === code);
  }
```

I've been reading and looking for a solution but don't know how to solve it

Comment: Hi, somewhere in your code null values ​​are coming in. Possibly it is `value="{{provincias.code}}"`

Comment: NOTE: if you use ngModelChange instead of change: `(ngModelChange)="onSelect($event)"`, in $event you get the value of the select -you don't need fight with target.value-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because TypeScript doesn't automatically infer the type of the event target when you access event.target.value. To resolve this issue, you can explicitly typecast the event.target to an appropriate type.

```
onSelect($event: Event): void {
  const selectedValue = ($event.target as HTMLSelectElement).value;
  this.municipios = this.newPersonService
    .getMunicipios()
    .filter((item) => item.parent_code === selectedValue);
}
```

And in Html

```
<select
  [(ngModel)]="selectedProvincia"
  (change)="onSelect($event)"
  name="provincias"
  id="ps-prov"
  class="form-select"
>
  <option
    *ngFor="let provincias of provincias"
    value="{{provincias.code}}"
  >
    {{provincias.label}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

- You shouldn't create variables in loops with the same name as of list (`*ngFor="let provincias of provincias"` change variable name after `let` to singular form of word).
- Use ngModelChange instead of banana-in-a-box pattern `[()]` if you rely on model change event.
- Also great pattern would be to create method `getMunicipiosByCode(code: string)`.

---

```
<select [ngModel]="selectedProvincia" (ngModelChange)="onSelect($event)">
  <option *ngFor="let provincia of provincias" [value]="provincia.code">
    {{ provincia.label }}
  </option>
</select>


onSelect(code: string): void {
  this.municipios = this.newPersonService
    .getMunicipios()
    .filter((item) => item.parent_code === code);
}
```